# Winforms bind to a combobox in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView which I have a BindingSource bound to, to display a collection of objects. I can easily databind TextboxColumn's to the DataGridView to display the data from the data source.

However, one of the properties of the data source is a choice object. I have tried to databind a ComboboxColumn with the grid but have had no joy in displaying the text of the choice property.

I have the following:

```
// bind to the datagrid
this.datagridBindingSource.DataSource = collectionForDatagrid;
this.dataGrid.DataSource = this.datagridBindingSource.DataSource;

// now bind the collection of choices to the combobox column
this.choiceDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = choiceCollection;

// set the display and value members of the combobox
this.choiceDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.choiceDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "ID";
```

But nothing seems to be displayed in the combobox. The "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" are properties of the objects in "choiceCollection".

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `Property` in your DataSource you want to bind to your `choiceDataGridViewComboBoxColumn`?

Comment: You noticed the issue at the same time as myself!...I did not in fact set the "DataPropertyName" property. The number of times I think of the answer the very second I press "post"!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, rookie mistake! I forgot the following line:

```
this.choiceDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID";
```