# Bind Data To combo box column in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a DataGridView with combo box column. For the combo box column I want to bind GroupName and GroupId. I'm binding GroupName as display member.

```
dgvRoster[j, i].Value = GroupName;
```

How can I bind GroupId as Value Member?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "ID";
this.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID";
```

i believe this is what you are missing.
i also suggest you take a look here [Binding a combobox inside a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130299/winforms-bind-to-a-combobox-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: Is that possible to set display member and value member for specific cell like this? dgvRoster[j, i].ValueMember = "ID";